# Plotting a histogram, wrong alignment of bars and labelling

Tags: gnuplot

I'm having trouble with a gnuplot, somehow the x labelling shifts to the right (or the bars to the left) when defining

```
set style data histograms
```

The Plotscript:

```
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
set key inside left top vertical Right noreverse noenhanced autotitles nobox
set style histogram clustered gap 5 title  offset character 0, 0, 0
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by -45  offset character 0, 0, 0
set xtics  norangelimit font ",8"
set xlabel "Scaling Factor"
set ylabel "Execution time [ms]"
set title "Database performance db4o vs Sqlite - Testcase 1 [indexed]" 
set logscale y
set terminal pdf
set output 'db4o_vs_sqlite_indexed.pdf'
plot 'db4o_sb1-5idx.dat' using 3:xtic(1) title 'db4o', 'sqlite_sb1-5idx.dat' using 3 title 'Sqlite'
```

The data:

```
"Scaling Factor" "Testcase 1" "Testcase 2" "Testcase 3" "Testcase 4"
1 0 34 28 11
2 1 136 91 65
3 0 297 198 101
4 0 487 297 214
10 0 3124 1896 1567
20 0 13000 7907 7628
```

[image: The outcome]

Comment: What does the other data file look like?  From the one you posted I'm guessing that is the sqlite data, but the other file is the one from where the tic labels are being read.

Comment: The other file is looking exactly the same. It is working if I'm removing the first line of the data files, but I still don't know why.

Comment: Is this question still open? Which version of Gnuplot are you using? I just tried with 4.6 and the tic-labels align with the bars.